# Many-to-many conditional fetch with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Say you have a **Many-to-Many** relationship between an Article entity and a User entity ("user can like an article"), which you've mapped with Doctrine annotations.

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="namespace\user")
private userlikes;
```

I would like to fetch my articles and to know whether for each fetched article, the current user likes it or not.

I could do two queries:

1. Fetch all articles, no condition
2. Fetch all articles, where `:user MEMBER OF article.userlikes`

Any way to do this in one query? Perhaps by somehow joining conditionally on userlikes?